# Pgrep returns mutiple PIDs

Tags: bash, shell-script

My script accepts a process name as an input and kills it.  I tried using pgrep but it's returning two PIDs , one for the process which is running and one for the script which accepts the process name as input, so am stuck! I tried using the `pgrep` `-fo` option too but that did not help either. Any suggestions would be helpful.
This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
ProcessName=$1

pID= pgrep -fl $ProcessName

echo $pID
```

So, when I invoke the script, it's returning two PIDs:

```
bash-3.00$ ./dynamic_values.sh test-Process

10534 /xxx/xxo/xxx/xxe --run --propFile /application/test/test-Process_Archive.tra --innerProcess
23401 /bin/bash ./dynamic_values.sh test-Process
```

I was expecting just 10534, but it picked up the script too . Version of OS just in case:

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a
Linux xxxxxx 2.6.9-67.0.1.
```

Comment: Why write a script for this? Lots of tools have already been written for these kind of jobs, you just need to find the right one. Based on your question, I would suggest you try `pkill`. It uses the same process findng logic as `pgrep` so you already know how to use it to find your process, but rather than returning the PID's to you, it just goes ahead and sends them a kill signal for you. In the mean time, it also takes care of details such as not killing itself.

Comment: `pkill` when using `-f` (which he is doing) will have the same problem.

Comment: @bahamat: Really? So do you have to use `-x` in combination with `-f` to make sure you are matching the whole thing? I'm surprised `pkill` doesn't have a built in way to handle this.

Comment: @Caleb From what I've experienced, on OS X and Solaris it does the right thing, but Linux uses a different implementation. I had to get real targeted with my regexp to get what I wanted on Linux (I was writing a script that would kill old instances of itself).

Comment: I have never had `pkill` kill itself before killing the processes I wanted to kill, so I'd always assumed the implementation was good.

Comment: @jw013 `pkill` and `pgrep` are identical except that one prints the pids and the other one sends a signal. They take care never to match themselves, but they can match their caller.

Comment: "Why run a script for this?" - Maybe it's the minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to tackle this same problem a couple of weeks ago. `pgrep` and `pkill` support extended regular expressions so it's a simple matter of getting the right regexp.

This is your script with the regexp that I used.

```
#!/bin/bash
ProcessName=$1

pID= pgrep -fl "^(/.*)?${ProcessName}\s"

echo $pID
```

Although using `pkill` (as Caleb suggested) is better.

```
pkill -fl "^(/.*)?${ProcessName}\s"
```

You may still need to tweak the regexp to get the desired results for your use case and how the program is being executed.

Now, if there *are* actually multiple processes running with that name they will of course be killed. If you want to avoid that you can use `-o` to kill only the *oldest* matching process or `-n` to kill only the *newest*. If you want only one, but neither the oldest or newest then you probably shouldn't be using `p(kill|grep)`.

Comment: bahamat , thank you for the tip and I was able to use regex successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't using

```
| grep -v $$
```

to exclude your process from the list help?

Comment: The point of `pgrep` and `pkill` is that you don't have to pipe it to grep.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

ProcessName=$1

pID=`pgrep -fl $ProcessName`

echo "$pID" | grep -v  "^$$"
```

Comment: The point of `pgrep` and `pkill` is that you don't have to pipe it to grep.

Comment: it depends. in this case we should filter out current process by it's pid

Comment: No, you don't understand. The one and only point of `pgrep` is to not pipe to `grep`. If you're going to use `grep` you might as well use `ps | grep`.

Comment: I am afraid *you* have misunderstanding here. main point of prep look up processes based on name and *other        attributes*

Comment: Years ago during the Solaris start up every init script called the equivalent of `kill $(ps -ef | grep somedaemon | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')`. The extra forks were increasing the boot up time by launching 5x the number of processes necessary. `pkill` and `pgrep` were written so you could just call `pkill somedaemon` and significantly reduce boot up times.

Answer (score 0):

if you exclude the #!/bin/bash then it will not fork another process for the script but you will lose the choice of what shell it runs with. bash is default enough though and those that are smiler should be able to run this.

not sure if that will get rid of the second process ID though.

I understand this is not complete but it is late and I have to work in the am but this "should" work as a quick fix.

Comment: thanks for taking time this late in the evening , unfortunately it returns an empty string as well as the correct pid,like this  bash-3.00$ ./dynamic_values.sh test-Process
10534 /opt/XXengine --run --propFile /opt/application/test/test-Process_Archive.tra --innerProcess                                                                                                                 $